# Adding spaces before values in DataTable column

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a DataTable column with values that contain numbers and letters. For example:

- `"2A"`
- `"13ABC"`
- `"412BBIL"`

I am using the loop below to add spaces before each value of each row in that DataTable. However, the loop that I am using counts every character - I just need it to count ONLY numbers and ignore any non-number (like spaces, or special characters).

To clarify even further, `"412BBIL"` has 3 digits, `"13ABC"` has 2 digits, and `"2A"` has 1 digit.

- 3 digits is the current max in this example `"412BBIL"` and because it has the maximum number of digits in the column, no spaces are added.
- Because `"13ABC"` has 2 digits (and therefore one less than the maximum), it would add one space -> `" 13ABC"`.
- Because `"2A"` has 1 digit (and therefore two less than the maximum), it would add 2 spaces -> `"  2A"`.

My code currently works pretty great (but it's probably not the best way to do this) - I just need it to count only numbers, instead of every character. How do I adjust my below code to accomplish what I need in the most efficient way possible?

```
string maxString = dtDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row["NumberColumn"].ToString())
    .OrderByDescending(st => st.Length).FirstOrDefault();

int maxStringLength = 0;    
foreach (char c in maxString)
{//Get the maximum character length in column
    if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
    {
        maxStringLength++;
    }
}

//minStringLength = the minimum character length in column
int minString = 0;
int minStringLength = 9999;
for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    minString = 0;
    foreach (char c in dtDataTable.Rows[i]["NumberColumn"].ToString())
    {
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            minString++;
        }
    }
    if ((minString <= minStringLength) && (minString != 0))
    {
        minStringLength = minString;
    }
}

//Add Spaces
int tempInt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    tempInt = 0;
    foreach (char c in dtDataTable.Rows[i]["NumberColumn"].ToString())
    {
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {//char.IsDigit(c) might work
            tempInt++;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x != (maxStringLength - tempInt); x++)
    {
        dtDataTable.Rows[i]["NumberColumn"] = " " + dtDataTable.Rows[i]["NumberColumn"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (char.IsDigit(c)) tempInt++;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `@"^\d+"` Regex pattern to get the longest number in the column and use it to [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netcore-3.1) the numeric parts with a padding character of your choice. For that, the `@"^(\d+)(.*)$"` Regex pattern in the loop is to capture the numeric part and the rest of the value in [Match.Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match.Groups);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netcore-3.1) to do the required padding and finally concatenate the values of the groups to set the new value.

```cs
var cn = "NumberColumn";
var groupPatt = @"^(\d+)(.*)$";
var maxLenPatt = @"^\d+";
var paddingChar = ' ';
var maxDigitsLen = dtDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => Regex.Match(r.Field<string>(cn).TrimStart(paddingChar), 
    maxLenPatt).Length).Max();

foreach (var r in dtDataTable.AsEnumerable())
{
    var m = Regex.Match(r.Field<string>(cn).TrimStart(paddingChar),
        groupPatt, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (m.Success)
        r[cn] = string.Concat(m.Groups[1].Value.TrimStart(paddingChar)
            .PadLeft(maxDigitsLen, paddingChar), m.Groups[2].Value.Trim());
}
```

<sup>**Maybe:** Leading zeros instead of whites paces?</sup>

If you are trying to create fixed-length values in `NumberColumn`, then you could do instead:

```cs
var cn = "NumberColumn";
var paddingChar = '0';
var maxLen = dtDataTable.AsEnumerable().Max(r => r.Field<string>(cn).Length);

dtDataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(r => r[cn] = r.Field<string>(cn)
    .TrimStart(paddingChar).PadLeft(maxLen, paddingChar));
```

Comment: Ooh, this is cool. But may I ask how to adjust this code so that the spaces are added with (and sorry here, I don't know the right word) logic? Because the number of digits are going to be random and not limited to 3.

Comment: @lolikols Hello there. No matter 3 or more, the target numbers are `0-9` to insert two spaces, and `10-99` to insert one. Is that what you need? or you need to add some spaces if the length = 3 or more? The line `var len = Reg....` returns the number of digits. Whether `0` or more.

Comment: So basically, I need it to match up the length of numbers. So 9999ABC has 4 characters (numbers only), for example (the..."detection" of characters should ignore spaces and non-numbers). So now, if I have 2BCD. That's 1 character (again, ignoring spaces and non-numbers). The idea is to add enough spaces in front of the string so that the number of spaces added + the digits = the max number of digits in the column. So we would add 3 spaces to 2BCD.

Comment: Also, there is no telling what the minimum and maximum number of digits will be in that column, sadly :(.

Comment: @lolikols ahaa. Now it makes sense. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && !char.IsLetter(c))
        {
            tempInt++;
        }
```

It isn't the best way, but it keeps close to your original code. You could always uses regex.

Comment: May I ask what the best way is? Sorry - fairly new to coding.

Comment: Updated my original post because I just realized I'm missing a chunk of code in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `if (char.IsDigit(c)) tempInt++;` for numeric character.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, `char.IsDigit` returns true for more characters than `'0'..'9'` so it is best to be specific about what you are doing. For example, `char.IsDigit('๒')` also returns true. If you actually needs to detect `'0'..'9'`, so you can use `int digitCount = s.Count(c => '0' <= c && c <= '9')` where `s` is your string. You can then use `new string(' ', digitCount)` to create a new string with the amount of white space you need. So your code in the loop will be

```
var row = dtDataTable.Rows[i];
string s = row["NumberColumn"].ToString();
int digitCount = s.Count(c => '0' <= c && c <= '9');
string spaces = new string(' ', digitCount);
row["NumberColumn"] = spaces + s;
```

Comment: Will int digitCount = s.Count(c => '0' <= c && c <= '9') count spaces?

Comment: No. It counts only what between '0' and '9' inclusive. Anything in {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6',7','8','9'} to be specific.